# Screencapture with zooming

Tags: macos, screen-capture, defaults, zoom

In Snow Leopard when I used a screencapture program (⇧⌃⌘4) on the screen area that was zoomed in (by using ⌃ + mouse wheel) the resulting screen shot has the same zoom factor. Super useful when I wanted to take some small, detailed screen shot.

In 10.7 screencapture ignores the zoom factor and resulting screen shot is in 1:1 scale.

Is there some `defaults` setting, or anything else, that could bring back the SnowLeopard behavior?

Comment: Does it really matter? You still have the same number of pixels in the screenshot, therefore the same quality. The image you were getting before is just a pixelated copy of what you are getting now.

Comment: @spudwaffle It does matter to me because otherwise I have to change a size of my screen shot manually. I'm not after image quality, but I want to show (even pixelated) design detail of say 25 x 24 px (size in 1:1 scale) area of the screen.

Comment: Go with @Wheat Williams` answer.

Comment: There's got too be a better way than having to post-scale the screenshot. Zoomed screenshots makes for so much better WYSIWYG operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer appears to be "No". I have also tested this with the commercial screen-capture utility SnagIt, and it behaves the same way, which is different in Lion from the way it behaved in Snow Leopard.

My suggested work-around is to use Automator's built-in "Scale Images" action to create a workflow to scale your screen shots to the size you want.

[image]

[Commercial programs such as [GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.com/content/188/graphicconverter.html) and [Pixelmator](http://www.pixelmator.com/) can scale screen captures, and they also provide additional Automator actions with additional capabilities. You can see some of these in the example above--I own both GraphicConverter and Pixelmator, so these additional options are visible under Automator on my system.]

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I can confirm the same for the LittleSnapper.app. If nothing else, I'll use Automator action you suggested.